# Error al enviar correos en asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gmail

Estoy elaborando una sección de envío de correos en Asp.net y MVC, usando la librería Net.Mail y el servidor de gmail ya active el acceso de apps menos seguras, el error que manda es el siguiente:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Error al enviar correo.' WebException: No es posible conectar con el servidor remoto, SocketException: Se produjo un error durante el intento de conexión ya que la parte conectada no respondió adecuadamente tras un periodo de tiempo, o bien se produjo un error en la conexión establecida ya que el host conectado no ha podido responder 74.125.127.109:465**

Tengo esto en el archivo web.config:

```
 <system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="micorreo@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mi usuario" password="mi contraseña" 
             defaultCredentials="true"  />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Y tengo esto en el código para enviar el correo:

```
var smtpSection = (SmtpSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp");
        string Host = smtpSection.Network.Host;
        int Port = smtpSection.Network.Port;
        string UserName = smtpSection.From;
        string Pass = smtpSection.Network.Password;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(Host, Port);
        NetworkCredential cert = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Pass);
        smtp.Credentials = cert;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;


        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

        message.From = new MailAddress("Remitente@gmail.com");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("Destinatario@gmail.com"));


        message.Subject = "Asunto";
        message.Body = "Mensaje";
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"rutadelarchivo"));
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtp.Send(message);
```

De favor que puedan ayudarme a resolver este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te agrego el cuerpo de un metodo para enviar correo. como puedes ver los datos de cadena los puedes cambiar por parametros, y la funcion generaCuerpoCorreo puede contener el html que tienes al inicio de tu codigo, claro que debe ser de tipo string.

```
public void enviarCorreo() {

string deDireccionOrigen = "UniversidadCentral@gmail.com";

MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
{
    UserName = deDireccionOrigen,
    Password = "mipasSecreto" 
};

smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
message.From = new MailAddress(deDireccionOrigen);
message.To.Add(new MailAddress(alumno.CorreoElectronico));
message.Subject = "Solicidud de Tramite";
message.IsBodyHtml = true; 
message.Body = GeneraCuerpoCorreo(alumno.NombreCompleto);



smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.Send(message);

}
```

Comment: Que tal amigo saludos, probe con tu metodo y me sigue dando el mismo error

Comment: estas haciendo una prueba local ? revisa la configuracion en [gmail](https://aspnetcoremaster.com/.net/smtp/smptclient/dotnet/2018/07/22/enviar-un-correo-con-csharp-gmail.html)

Comment: Asi es hermano estoy probando en local, pues ya he activado el acceso a apps menos seguras, que otra configuración puedo revisar?

Comment: en tu maquina tienes fireawall o antivirus activado? puedes apagarlo un momento y hacer una prueba

Comment: Lo que pasa que estoy conectado a un accesso remoto que es donde esta el visual studio, entonces no tengo acceso al firewall y al antivirus, de hecho pregunte y me dijeron que no afecta

Comment: puedes hacer una prueba solo para verificar que te comunicas con ese servidor y ese puerto, en la maquina remota abre la ventana de comandos y ejecuta:  telnet smtp.gmail.com 587                                la respuesta debe ser 220 smtp.gmail.com ...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105167/discussion-between-miguel-zarate-and-juan-daniel-almeyda-calapiz).